# Existence of a Repeating Divisor

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, prime-factorization, square-numbers

I have $n$ integers $a_1, a_2, a_3, .., a_n$ let $X = a_1*a_2*a_3*...*a_n$. I want to know a single integer $F$ such that $F^2$ divides $X$. It is told that there will be atleast one such $X$ and there can be many possible $F$'s, But i only need one. One easy solution is to prime factorize all the numbers and see if any divisor appears more than once, but since $a_i$ can be upto 10^18 it is not possible to factorize all the numbers. Is there any faster solution?

Comment: $F=1$ works ...

Comment: If you want an $F>1$, then compute pairwise greatest common divisors between the $a_i$s. If you find one that's not $1$, that can be your $F$ too.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Procedure) on all $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ pairs of $a_i$ and $a_j$. If you get a GCD that is $F > 1$, then that is your answer. This is because $F \mid a_i$ and $F \mid a_j$, so when you multiply them together, you get $F^2 \mid (a_ia_j)$, so $F^2 \mid X$.

Euclidean algorithm runs in $O(\log a_i+\log a_j)$, so since $a_i \leq 10^{18}$, it should be negligible. Thus, the algorithm will run in $O(n^2(\log a_i+\log a_j))=O(n^2)$.

However, unfortunately, we also need to check that all of the $a_i$ are square-free. According to [this MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16098/complexity-of-testing-integer-square-freeness), this problem is in NP and co-NP, so I don't think there's a much better algorithm of doing this then finding all of the prime divisors of $a_i$ and $a_j$. Maybe [Pollar's rho algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) can help here?

Comment: Suppose the numbers are 3, 5, 7, 16
But here this doesn't work, I still need to factorize one integer

Comment: @Swatak Ah...Good point. That makes the problem more complicated because we also need to keep track of numbers like $48$ which aren't perfect squares but have a perfect square as a divisor.

Comment: @Swatak Checking if a number is square-free is in NP, so there's no polynomial-time algorithm for solving this problem.